# How to solve a power/polynomial equation

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Is there a method to solve such equations : $AB^{x} + C x = D$ ? with $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ real parameters and $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $B>0$?

Comment: what is $x$? real?

Comment: Yes indeed, I corrected the question thank you.

Comment: Is $B$ assumed to be positive? If not then $B^x$ becomes problematic...

Comment: Yes B is assumed to B positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, three degenerate cases;

1. If $C=0$ and $B=1$ then the equation reduces to $A=D$, and there is nothing to solve.
2. If $C=0$ and $B\neq1$ then $AB^x=D$ and hence $x=\frac{\ln{\frac{D}{A}}}{\ln{B}}$.
3. If $C\neq0$ and $B=1$ then $A+Cx=D$ and hence $x=\frac{D-A}{C}$.

If $C\neq0$ and $B\neq1$ then setting $a:=\frac{A}{C}$ and $d:=\frac{D}{C}$ yields
$$aB^x=d-x.$$
Setting $y:=d-x$ and $v:=B^{-1}$ and $u:=aB^d$ then yields
$$y=aB^{d-y}=aB^dB^{-y}=uv^y=ue^{y\ln{v}},$$
where $e$ denotes Euler's constant. Finally setting $z:=-y\ln{v}$ and rearranging yields the equation
$$ze^z=-u\ln{v},$$
which has no 'elementary' closed form solution in general. The solution to this is precisely what the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) denotes. That is, by definition we have $z=W(-u\ln{v})$. Substituting everything back yields
$$-\left(\frac{D}{C}-x\right)\ln{B^{-1}}=W\left(-\frac{A}{C}B^{\frac{D}{C}}\ln{B^{-1}}\right),$$
and isolating $x$ shows that
$$x=\frac{D}{C}-\frac{1}{\ln{B}}W\left(\frac{A}{C}B^{\frac{D}{C}}\ln{B}\right).$$
Finding exact values of the Lambert W function in terms of elementary functions is in general not possible, though of course there are practical algorithms for numerical approximations.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, very interesting stuff. What would be the conditions on A,B,C and D for which $W\left(\frac{A}{C}B^{\frac{D}{C}}\ln{B^{-1}}\right)$ could be expressed in terms of elementary function ?

Comment: See the wikipedia section on [special values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Special_values) for a few known values of $W(z)$, which you can then translate to conditions on $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$. One condition that particularly jumps out is $A=0$, and then obviously $x=\frac{D}{C}$, but otherwise the expression seems too convoluted to say anything nice about. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know if this list is exhaustive ?

Comment: I have no doubt there are much more extensive lists, though I don't know where to find them. If there are particular values you are interested in, perhaps wolfram alpha can help you.

Comment: Good advice ! Thank you very much !

Comment: I see that wolfram alpha gives me an approximate solution for fixed value of the parameters (A,B,C and D). I imagine it uses a numerical method to find an approximate solution ?

Comment: Indeed it does.

Comment: Should it not be $ze^z = - u ln(v) $ ?

Comment: You are right, I have edited accordingly.